# How to compute this integral without using residues?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> How to compute
>
> $$\int_C \frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2 + i)^2} dz, $$
> where $C = \{|z| = 3\}$.

I tried a lot of ways through partial fractions but it didn't seem to work
any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried residues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned a few times, apply the residue theorem.  This means finding the poles of the integrand, which are at

$$z^2+i=0 \implies z = \pm e^{i 3 \pi/4}$$

These are double roots, so the residues at these poles may be found by the following expressions:

$$r_+ = \operatorname*{Res}_{z=e^{i 3 \pi/4}} \frac{e^{i z}}{(z^2+i)^2} = \left [\frac{d}{dz} \frac{e^{i z}}{(z+e^{i 3 \pi/4})^2} \right ]_{z=e^{i 3 \pi/4}}$$

$$r_- = \operatorname*{Res}_{z=-e^{i 3 \pi/4}} \frac{e^{i z}}{(z^2+i)^2} = \left [\frac{d}{dz} \frac{e^{i z}}{(z-e^{i 3 \pi/4})^2} \right ]_{z=-e^{i 3 \pi/4}}$$

The integral is then $i 2 \pi (r_++r_-)$.

Comment: Computing that derivative and evaluating it at z is pretty nasty. I basically told the OP that if $f(z_0)$ is not $0$ and $h^{'}(z_0)$ is not $0$ then $res_{z=0}g(z) = \frac{f(z_0)}{h^{'}(z_0)}$, where $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{h(z)}$. However, your solution is much more clear, so an upvote this deserves. :)

Comment: @Faraad: thanks.  I disagree, though, unless you find the quotient rule nasty.  I don't.  You should finish cleaning up your solution.

Comment: Yes, I do. Thanks. I'm new to complex analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Here you want to apply the Residue Theorem.

$(1)$\ $\int_{|z|=3}\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+i)^2}=2\pi i(\sum res_{z=z_k}f(z))$.

$(2)$ The residues of $f$ that you need to compute are at the singular points of $f$, which by inspection are the second roots of -i. You can easily verify that the second roots of -i are: $e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}}$,$e^{\frac{7\pi i}{4}}$.

$(3)$ Let $z_0=e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}},z_1=e^{\frac{7\pi i}{4}}$.

$(3)$ Now compute the residues in the following manner, $res_{z=z_k}f(z)=(\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+i)^2}\frac{d}{dz})|_{z=z_k}$, for $k=0,1$.

$(4)$ Finish by using $(1)$

Comment: @bebo, I made a correct. This should be second roots of $-1$. Solve $z^2+i=0$.

Comment: OK then.  As you are new, I will kindly point out that your expression for the residue blows up by definition of $z_k$.  Try again.

Comment: Wow. Yeah originally I had the second roots of i when it was suppose to be the second roots of -i and I never changed my solution. Thanks a lot. That's pretty embarrassing.